# How to use Average and Groupby using EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Entity named "transactions" with {Id, RawDateTime, Score,SId}

I want to get a average of Score per day for records having SId. What am I doing wrong here?

`_context.transactions.Where(b => b.SId == request.Id) .GroupBy(a=>a.RawDateTime.Date).Include(b=>b.Average(v=>v.Score)) .ToListAsync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this would be

```
_context.transactions.Where(b => b.SId == request.Id)
    .GroupBy(a=>a.RawDateTime.Date)
    .Select(c => new { Id = c.Key, Ave = c.Average(v => v.Score) })
    .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: But how to get Date and Score as output?

Comment: `Key` is Date, and `Ave` is average score. So, with LINQ statement above you get both